# How to enable the addition of an extra parameter to URL.Action via an Extension method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am trying to understand how I can add an extra parameter to URL.Action, and have it as part of the resultant link.

Lets assume the following:

```
myParm = "myTestParameterValue";
@Url.Action("Edit", "Order", new { id=item.Id}, null,myParm)
```

which would result in:

```
/Order/Edit/1/myTestParameterValue
```

I would really appreciate some sample code of the extension method for this Action Sample to see how the parameters are taken in and how the link is generated.

I guess it would start something like:

```
public static MvcHtmlString Action(this HtmlHelper helper, string actionName, string controllerName, object routeValues, boolean IsHashRequired)

If (IsHashRequired)
{
  String myHash = GetHash();
}

// Pseudocode .... string myNewLink = ... + myHash
```

Many thanks in advance

EDIT

I need to calculate hash to add to resultant link. A better parameter would be a boolean. I have edited code accordingly.

EDIT2:

```
    public static IHtmlString Action(this UrlHelper urlHelper, string actionName, string controllerName, object routeValues, string protocol, bool isHashRequired )
{

     if (isHashRequired)
     {
         routeValues["hash"] = "dskjdfhdksjhgkdj"; //Sample value.
     }
     return urlHelper.Action(???); // Resultant URL = /Order/Edit/1/dskjdfhdksjhgkdj
}
```

EDIT3:

Struggling with :

```
return urlHelper.Action(actionName, controllerName, routeValues, protocol);
```

Apparently needs converting to IHtmlString??

EDIT4:

```
    public static String Action(this UrlHelper urlHelper, string actionName, string controllerName, object routeValues, string protocol, bool isHashRequired )
{

    RouteValueDictionary rvd = new RouteValueDictionary(routeValues);
    if (isHashRequired)
    {
        string token = "FDSKGLJDS";
        rvd.Add("urltoken", token);
    }
     return urlHelper.Action(actionName, controllerName, rvd, protocol); //rvd is incorrect I believe
}
```

EDIT5

```
    return urlHelper.Action(actionName, controllerName, rvd, protocol,null);
```

where

rvd is the RouteValueDictionary
  hostname is null.

Thanks...

Comment: this would be part of your routing, not part of the `.Action` extension method.

Comment: Really appreciating Daniel's help here, so not sure who downvoted and why ??? Oh well, I am sure I will get to the answer thanks to Daniel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should consider modifying your routes

Where you have your routing configured add something like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "hash",                                                            // Route name
  "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{hash}",                               // URL with parameters
  new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "", hash = "" }  // Parameter defaults
);
```

And use `URL.Action` like this:

```
myParm = "myTestParameterValue";
@Url.Action("Edit", "Order", new { id=item.Id, hash = myParm}, null);
```

You can easily add this with a new extension method class

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static IHtmlString ActionWithHash(this UrlHelper urlHelper, ....)
    {
         if (hashRequired)
         {
             routeParameters["hash"] = ...
         }
         return urlHelper.Action(...);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I am actually using this extension method to add a security token, so need code to generate a Hash, hence the need for an extension method. The Parameter is probably more likely to be a boolean ie "IsHashRequired", if true, then calculate hash and add as new parameter in resultant link.

Comment: Just added an edit of my code so far. Sorry I need a few more "dots" filling in. Really appreciate your help so far.

Comment: Sorry think I have got this now.

Comment: Struggling with return, issue with IHtmlString and string conversion, see Edit3. Thanks

Comment: Added later version of code to EDIT4. There is an error with RouteValues and how I am returning it. Cannot see the answer myself.

Comment: The final bit of this answer is about how to convert a RouteValueDictionary to an object so I can return it. However I did find an option to pass a RouteValueDictionary value, where one has to specify the HostName as well which I provided "null" for. Bit of a workaround as I guess I should be able to pass back an object. See EDIT5 above.